# Atom Editor Opens Strange Window Upon Launch

Tags: atom-editor

I installed atom about a week ago and it worked fine until last night when it suddenly ceased working and opens some dev-tool stuff when I launch Atom.

I get this in the console:

```
index.js:87 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Noah Hefner\.atom\compile-cache\less\40e22529c8729b65e1d700a7ae3f73d57ed1288f\imports.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as openSync] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:168:20)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1343:33)
    at Proxy.writeFileSync (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\node_modules\fs-plus\lib\fs-plus.js:298:29)
    at LessCache.module.exports.LessCache.writeJson (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\node_modules\less-cache\lib\less-cache.js:212:23)
    at LessCache.module.exports.LessCache.setImportPaths (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\node_modules\less-cache\lib\less-cache.js:161:18)
    at new LessCache (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\node_modules\less-cache\lib\less-cache.js:68:18)
    at new LessCompileCache (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\less-compile-cache.js:21:26)
    at ThemeManager.module.exports.ThemeManager.loadLessStylesheet (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\theme-manager.js:283:32)
    at ThemeManager.module.exports.ThemeManager.loadStylesheet (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\theme-manager.js:271:27)
    at ThemeManager.module.exports.ThemeManager.requireStylesheet (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\theme-manager.js:191:30)
    at ThemeManager.module.exports.ThemeManager.reloadBaseStylesheets (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\theme-manager.js:252:25)
    at ThemeManager.module.exports.ThemeManager.loadBaseStylesheets (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\theme-manager.js:248:25)
    at AtomEnvironment.module.exports.AtomEnvironment.initialize (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\atom-environment.js:339:25)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Noah Hefner\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.18.0\resources\app\src\initialize-application-window.js:102:29)
    at setupWindow (file:///C:/Users/Noah%20Hefner/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.18.0/resources/app/static/index.js:106:12)
    at window.onload (file:///C:/Users/Noah%20Hefner/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.18.0/resources/app/static/index.js:67:9)handleSetupError @ index.js:87
```

Here is a picture of the window I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when it's installed somewhere that your account lacks read/write permissions. You should find the properties of directory `C:\Users\Noah Hefner\.atom` and give `SYSTEM` full permissions.

If that does not work, you could always just reinstall Atom.